# What is wrong with my solution of SPOJ ACTIV?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Here is the link for the problem:[SPOJ - ACTIV](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACTIV/)

I came up with the recurrence for the problem as:

```
F(i) = 1+F(i+1)+F(next(activities[i].endtime))
```

where next() finds out the index of the activity with start time>= end time of the current activity, while the activities have been sorted in increasing order of their Start time.

This is my java solution, although it passes many test cases of SPOJ toolkit, however it does give WA for some. What is the problem in my concept/solution?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Pair<T>{
    final T x;
    final T y;
    Pair(T a, T b){
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }
}

public class Activities{
    private static int search(Pair<Integer> []p,int key, int l, int h)
    {
        int ll=l;
        while(l<h)
        {
            int mid = (l+h)/2;
            if(p[mid].x < key)l=mid+1;
            else if(p[mid].x == key){
                while(mid>=ll && p[mid].x == key)mid--;
                return mid+1;
            }
            else h=mid;
        }
        if(l==h && l>=0 && p[l].x>=key)return l;
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        final long mod = 100000000;
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(true)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(buff.readLine());
        if(n==-1)return;
        Pair <Integer> p [] = new Pair[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String [] in = buff.readLine().split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(in[0]), y = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
            p[i] = new <Integer>Pair(x,y);
        }
        Arrays.sort(p, new Comparator<Pair<Integer>>(){
            public int compare(Pair<Integer> p1, Pair<Integer> p2){
                if(p1.x == p2.x)return p1.y - p2.y;
                else return p1.x - p2.x;
            }
        });

        long dp[] = new long[n];
        dp[n-1] = 1;
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            int idx = search(p,p[i].y,i,n-1);
            dp[i] = 1+dp[i+1];
            if(idx != -1)dp[i]=dp[i]+dp[idx];
        }
        String res = (dp[0]%mod)+"";
        while(res.length()<8)res = '0'+res;
        System.out.println(res);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is able to exceed a `long` type scope. You should perform your calculation with more frequent casting to the `[0, mod)` range. This should be enough to fix your issue and solve this Spoj's problem:

```
for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
{
    int idx = search(p,p[i].y,i,n-1);
    dp[i] = 1+dp[i+1]%mod;
    if(idx != -1)dp[i]=(dp[i]%mod+dp[idx]%mod)%mod;
}
```